# Android popup window onTouchIntercept not working

Tags: android

This is my popupwindow. but it is handling any touch events..

```
    popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, 300, 300, true);
    popup.showAsDropDown(v, -30, 0);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popup.setTouchable(true);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Touched in the window");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please tell me the problem with this code..

Comment: Fixed... Sorry!! for troubling you guys..

Answer (score 0):

For the sake helping  whoever stumbles upon this thread...

Instead of `setTouchInterceptor()`, I have been using `setOnClickListener()` or `setOnTouchListener()`, which are not members of PopupWindow, true, but I simply call a LayoutInflater to get meeself the popup (View) and then set it as the PopupWindow layout. Proceed to do MAGIC with the View member functions as it better suits you.

Code sample:

```
LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.my_popup_layout_id);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);


popup = new PopupWindow(context);
popup.setContentView(layout);
popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
//popup.setFocusable(true);
popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);


popup.showAsDropDown(anchorViewOfYourChoice, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);
```

Comment: Maybe it would also be possible to get the popup view using PopupWindow.getContentView(), but I haven't a test-bench environment at hand to test it out.